# /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so , abort crashes only on Android 12 devices

Tags: android, android-12

Recently I experienced the following crash on the Statistics platform，but don't know what the problem is。

Android Studio version: Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
CompileSdkVersion : 31
TargetSdkVersion : 28

Below is the so crash message:

```
Blockquote

Process Name: 'com.yy.reader'
Thread Name: 'ReferenceQueueD'
pid: 16810, tid: 16819  >>> com.yy.reader <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00fffffefffffff0
  x0   0000007c8cc166c0  x1   00ffffff00000000  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000000000
  x4   0000000000000010  x5   000000795ebf2754  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0001232700012354
  x8   02ffffff00000000  x9   02ffffff00000000  x10  00000000189a1128  x11  0000000000000000
  x12  00000000000000e0  x13  000123ab000123c0  x14  003a847bf79640ed  x15  000032b25d89e598
  x16  0000007c82bd0540  x17  0000007c8cb81e38  x18  000000795e5fa000  x19  00ffffff00000000
  x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000007c8cc166c0  x22  0000000000000000  x23  000000001b551758
  x24  0000000070d9ab90  x25  000000001b551798  x26  0000000000000000  x27  00000079dd018000
  x28  0000000000000043  x29  000000795ebf26e0  x30  0000007c86f01858
  sp   000000795ebf26d0  pc   0000007c8cb8754c  pstate 0000000060001000
  v0   00000000000000000000000000000000  v1   00012e2e00012e5500012e94000123f9
  v2   00000079e08ce1d000000079e08ce180  v3   00000000000001400000000000000140
  v4   000000000002413000000000000240e0  v5   000024130000240e0000240900002404
  v6   00000000000000000000000000000000  v7   00000000000000008060180680601806
  v8   00000000000000000000000000000000  v9   00000000000000000000000000000000
  v10  00000000000000000000000000000000  v11  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v12  00000000000000000000000000000000  v13  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v14  00000000000000000000000000000000  v15  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v16  c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03  v17  80000000000000008000000000000000
  v18  80000000000000000000000000000000  v19  000000000000000000000000ebad8083
  v20  000000000000000000000000ebad8084  v21  000000000000000000000000ebad8085
  v22  000000000000000000000000ebad8086  v23  000000000000000000000000ebad8087
  v24  000000000000000000000000ebad8088  v25  000000000000000000000000ebad8089
  v26  000000000000000000000000ebad808a  v27  000000000000000000000000ebad808b
  v28  000000000000000000000000ebad808c  v29  000000000000000000000000ebad808d
  v30  000000000000000000000000ebad808e  v31  006d005f00790061006c00650064005f
  fpsr 00000010  fpcr 00000000
    #00 pc 000000000000654c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (_ZN5scudo9AllocatorINS_13AndroidConfigEXadL_Z21scudo_malloc_postinitEEE10deallocateEPvNS_5Chunk6OriginEmm+100)
    #01 pc 0000000000119854  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_6812RegexPattern3zapEv+212)
    #02 pc 0000000000119950  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_6812RegexPatternD2Ev+36)
    #03 pc 00000000000092e4  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicu_jni.so
    #04 pc 0000000000003978  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat
    --- --- --- ---
```

I couldn't reproduce this bug and didn't find information either.

Any information is appreciated. Thank you.